# Could not login into Facetime and Message 10.8.2

Tags: macos, messages, facetime

I did a clean install of Mountain Lion 10.8.2 on my MacBook Pro. Now I am facing some problem while loggin into Facetime and Message (could not sign in please check your network connection and try again). In console I am getting this message.

> apsd: Certificate not yet generated

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to change your DNS server settings.

I had this problems for a while, and a friend too, and the solution that worked for us was just changing the DNS servers to Google's DNS.

To do this, go to System Preferences > Network > Advanced > DNS >

Then press the + button on the left below DNS Servers, and add both:

8.8.8.8

and

8.8.4.4

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying but I already tried it, didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, and this fixed it for me.

Just open Terminal, and run these commands:

```
cd Library/Preferences
ls .GlobalPreferences.plist.*
rm .GlobalPreferences.plist.*
mv .GlobalPreferences.plist GlobalPreferences.plist.bak
```

After that, just reboot your Mac and FaceTime/iMessage should now work perfectly. Hope this helped!

SOURCE: http://xevio.us/blog/douglas/facetime-certificate-error-fixed-deleting-globalpreferencesplist

Comment: `ls: .GlobalPreferences.plist.*: No such file or directory`

Comment: It did that for me as well, however the problem was still fixed. Run the entire script at once by copying and pasting it all into Terminal, then press enter on the last step to finish. Then restart your Mac - it still works. I believe the author of this script used the middle two lines to ensure all files are deleted.

Comment: Thanks Faiz but still no luck.
still getting `apsd: Certificate not yet generated

` and `failed to get client cert on attempt 4,will try in 60 seconds`.

Comment: Open Keychain Access and click Certificates. Delete any untrusted certificates. Does this help?

Comment: Also, is your date/time synched with Apple's server? Go to System Preferences, click Date and Time, choose the Date & Time tab and check the 'Set date and time automatically' checkbox.

Comment: Also (sorry for all the comments :D) try this in a Terminal:

    sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imagent.plist

Comment: actually I did a clean install a week ago from the disk image that was downloaded from a different apple account. is this causing the trouble ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be. Have you attempted what I advised?

Comment: I've tried everything you suggested, nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem in 10.8.5 Messages caused by mistakenly entered filtering rules in LittleSnitch. After I disabled deny rules for the following services, the login problem went away: apsd, fpsaud, and ubd.